# SSH With Remote Login/Commands

Tags: unix, ssh

How can I use SSH to send multiple commands to a networked system, logging in as root, and providing a password?

I know you can do:

```
ssh -l <username> target_host
```

to login, but I'm not sure how to provide the password and a command so it all gets executed in one line.  I'm looking to make a script with many one-liner commands to the networked system that can be run as a one-off from another computer.

Comment: I would recommend setting up keyed authentication.

Comment: SSHing into root seems like an ungood idea. This isn't something you could do with a cron job?

Comment: Also don't be surprised if a lot of machines have sshd configured to automatically drop all root requests.  It's not good.

Comment: I work with embedded systems and its just to set them up for testing a little faster.  I'd agree its a bad idea in production though, haha.  Thanks for the input guys, I understand it now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ssh root@host "command"**

ie: ssh root@192.168.1.1 "cat /etc/fstab"

If you are trying to execute multiple commands, I would suggest looking into some form of Expect scripting.  I personally am a fan of Pexpect (Python).

Using keys to circumvent password prompt (from man ssh):

> The file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys lists the public keys that are
>   permitted
>        for logging in.  When the user logs in, the ssh program tells the
>   server
>        which key pair it would like to use for authentication.  The
>   client
>        proves that it has access to the private key and the server
>   checks that
>        the corresponding public key is authorized to accept the account.
>
> The user creates his/her key pair by running ssh-keygen(1).  This
>   stores
>        the private key in ~/.ssh/identity (protocol 1), ~/.ssh/id_dsa
>   (protocol
>        2 DSA), or ~/.ssh/id_rsa (protocol 2 RSA) and stores the public
>   key in
>        ~/.ssh/identity.pub (protocol 1), ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub (protocol 2
>   DSA), or
>        ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (protocol 2 RSA) in the user's home directory. 
>   The
>        user should then copy the public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys in
>   his/her
>        home directory on the remote machine.  The authorized_keys file
>   corre‐
>        sponds to the conventional ~/.rhosts file, and has one key per
>   line,
>        though the lines can be very long.  After this, the user can log
>   in with‐
>        out giving the password.

Comment: That looks good, but what about providing a password for root within the command? :)

Comment: Considering the circumstances, this is OK. You'll have to copy your local user's id_rsa.pub into /root/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote system. If it doesn't work, it's likely you have the wrong permissions on the authorized_keys file or .ssh dir on the remote (should be owned by root and 700 for the dir, 600 for the file)

Answer (score 2):

You can always do

```
ssh user@targetHost 'cd /tmp; ls -l'
```

or

```
myDir="/tmp"
ssh  user@targetHost "cd $myDir; ls -l"
```

I have chained together full shell scripts as the 'command' arugment, but I don't recommend it (any more) ;-0! .

Instead, copy your script to the remote machine and then just run it

```
 ssh user@targetHost 'yourRemoteScript'
```

Finally, you can't provide password with wrapping the whole thing in `expect`, which many systems don't have, many won't allow, etc. If you want unattended operation, you **have to** use the ssh_keys. Search here on S.O. for many postings on exactly  how to do it.

Good luck and I hope this helps.